# Passing the foreign key to the edit / delete view grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a set of `stream` videos which has as foreign key the `district` they belong to.
However, then I click on either the `edit` or `delete` button, I get;

```
Error 2012-08-30 23:51:16,424 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MissingMethodException occurred when processing request: [GET] /ctv/stream/list
No signature of method: ctv.Stream.findAllByDistrict() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: findAllByDistrict([Ljava.lang.Object;). Stacktrace follows:
Message: No signature of method: ctv.Stream.findAllByDistrict() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: findAllByDistrict([Ljava.lang.Object;)
```

The problem is because

```
<g:form>
  <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${streamInstance?.id}" />
  <span class="button"><g:actionSubmit class="edit" action="edit" id="${params['district']}" value="${message(code: 'default.button.edit.label', default: 'Edit')}" /></span>
  <span class="button"><g:actionSubmit class="delete" action="delete" id="${params['district']}" value="${message(code: 'default.button.delete.label', default: 'Delete')}" onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'default.button.delete.confirm.message', default: 'Are you sure?')}');" /></span>
</g:form>
```

I'm trying to send the `district` id to the `edit` page, but I'm not being able to. Could someone please help me with that? Suppose `district=10`, then I need to pass the value `10` through the `<g:actionSubmit>` tag. How could I do that?

Comment: Show us your Controller code where te edit action is triggered. Or are you using `static scaffold = true`?

Comment: @nickdos: I use `static scaffold = true `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [actionSubmit](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/actionSubmit.html) tag dosent support the id param. It only support action and value.

You have to put the district id in a hidden field

```
<g:hiddenField name="district" value="${params['district']}" />
```

Comment: So do you know how to access the hidden field from the other view?

Comment: Sometimes `params['district']` is empty.

Comment: check the form source with firebug to be sure that the hidden field is correctly filled

Answer (score 0):

Use simple g:link `<g:link action="edit" id="${streamInstance.id}"  >` there is no need of g:form here.
Also check if your controller settings.

```
class MakeAppController {
static allowedMethods = [ update: "POST", delete: "GET",save: "GET"]
```

Because Grails framework allow to make checks in controller for requests.